# How can I dynamically fill data to combo box depending upon another combo box value?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

I am new to Zend framework. now I am playing with Zend form. i need to load database values to a combo box depends upon another combo box value.

IE. When I am selecting a country another combo box should need to list states within that country. also everything want to load from database.

I tried Google many times for a solution but I couldn't find anything.

## My code below

//Loading Countries

```
$tblCoun = new Application_Model_DbTable_TblCountry();
$options = $tblComp->fetchCountiesPair();    
$tblCoun = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("cmbCountry");
$tblCoun ->setLabel("Select Country")
         ->setRequired(true)
         ->setAttrib("class", "form-control span-12");
$company->addMultiOptions($options);
$tblCoun = new Application_Model_DbTable_TblCountry();
$options = $tblComp->fetchCountiesPair();
```

//Here I need to load states

```
$tblStat = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("cmbStates");
$tblStat->setLabel("Select State")
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setAttrib("class", "form-control span-12");
$tblStat->addMultiOptions($options);
```

Comment: Do you have knowledge of jquery ajax?

Comment: yaah i know ajax but i like to use zend Technic to fill data..is there any built in option to do that?

Comment: Recently I have done same thing in my last zend project. I have used jquery ajax in it.

Comment: can you share me some sample code please.

Comment: I have tried to show you sample code. but it's very large code so I will provide you some abstract idea soon.

Answer (score 1):

Enable your layout and add this code in it:

```
<?php echo $this->docType(); ?>
<html>
  <head>
  <?php
    $this->headLink()->setStylesheet($this->baseUrl('js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css'));
    echo $this->headLink(). PHP_EOL;
    $this->headScript()->setFile($this->baseUrl('js/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js'));
    echo $this->headScript();
  ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now go to your view and add jquery ajax code something like this:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
  //For States
  $.post('<?php echo $this->baseUrl('ajax/states'); ?>', {'country': $(this).val()},
  function(data) {
     $('#state').html(data);
  });
});
```

I have defined separate controller for ajax request you can do it as you like here is some sample code:

```
public function statesAction() {
  $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
  $country = $this->getRequest()->getParam('country');

  $countryMapper = new Application_Model_CountryMapper();
  $states = $countryMapper->fetchAllStates($country);
  $this->view->states = $states;
}
```

As I have ajax Controller with statesAction I have view for that with following code:

```
  <option value="">Select States</option>
  <?php foreach($this->states as $state): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $state->value; ?>"><?php echo $state->name; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is just a rough idea. There is possibility of typo in my code as i have taken it from my project.

I Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ajax for this scenario, please follow this steps,

1] Onchange of country dropdown sent ajax call to server with selected countryID.
2] fetch all child records for that countryID and send then back to calling function.
3] remove existing state select box and populate with new entries using following.

```html
for(i=0; i < states.length; i++)
  $("#state").append('<option value=' + states[i]['stateID'] + '>' + states[i]['name'] + '</option>');
}
```